# Troubleshooting Window Leaking From Top of Frame

Tags: windows, roof, leaking, leaks

https://imgur.com/a/ruRV6Rf - Link to all the relevant photos and videos

I have a [water leaking situation](https://imgur.com/D3HBdAg) that I am trying to troubleshoot. Window installer says it's the roof. HOA says it's the windows and that if it was the roof, there would be water in the attic or coming down the walls elsewhere. I had the window company come out and [re-caulk the outside of the windows](https://imgur.com/zdeOlFZ) and then follow that up with a water test where we blasted a hose at the trim from point blank for a few minutes and no water came through. The leaking usually only occurs with harder driving rains. I'm on the top floor (2nd story) and there are no units above me. The building was built in the mid 90's. The roof was replaced in 2012. The windows were replaced (with retrofits) in mid 2016. The leaking began in 2021. The walls/exterior of the building is stucco. The roof is shown in the [IMGUR link](https://imgur.com/nV6XoTd) and those conduits were installed after the leaking started so that's not the cause of the problem.

My question is, how do I go about troubleshooting this further. What are the things I need to know about retrofitting windows with stucco? What do I need to know about the flashing over the nailing flange of the window so the buildings drainage plane can direct water outside? Since the water isn't coming directly from the window itself, where would the water be entering?

Comment: This is not a vinyl window insert problem since the water is coming in between the original window frame and the vinyl window. You do not show the stucco between the top of the window and the underside of the roof. Is there a vent in the area? You say this only happens during driving rain conditions. I have seen cases where the wind pushes the rain back into openings in the area above a window, causing leaks. Has the attic been inspected for water damage at the exterior wall?